# How to change RTK Query format

Tags: redux-toolkit, rtk-query

How to change rtk query response error format from

```
error: {
  data: {
    message: "error!",
  }
  status: 400,
}
```

to

```
error: {
  message: 'error!',
  status: 400,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to either just send `"error"` instead of `{ message: "error" }` from your server or you would need to reimplement `fetchBaseQuery`.